# Adding active class on scroll applying at bottom not top

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to implement some code I found on SO which adds the class "active" when the matching div is on the page. So scroll down, get to the div and the active class is added to the correct menu item. 
Currently, it is working but with some hitches, right now it's applying the active class at the bottom of the div, not when it hits the top. So I think I am at a bit of a loss.

Here is the current JS:

```
<script>
    // Cache selectors
    var lastId,
        topMenu = $("#nav"),
        topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+15,
        // All list items
        menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
        // Anchors corresponding to menu items
        scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
        var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
        if (item.length) { return item; }
        });

    // Bind click handler to menu items
    // so we can get a fancy scroll animation
    menuItems.click(function(e){
    var href = $(this).attr("href"),
        offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top-topMenuHeight+1;
    $('html, body').stop().animate({ 
        scrollTop: offsetTop
    }, 300);
    e.preventDefault();
    });

    // Bind to scroll
    $(window).scroll(function(){
    // Get container scroll position
    var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;

    // Get id of current scroll item
    var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
        if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
        return this;
    });
    // Get the id of the current element
    cur = cur[cur.length-1];
    var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";

    if (lastId !== id) {
        lastId = id;
        // Set/remove active class
        menuItems
            .parent().removeClass("active")
            .end().filter("[href='#"+id+"']").parent().addClass("active");
    }                   
    });
</script>
```

You can view the original js here on jsfiddle but mine is not acting like this one: http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/up4nu/

The issue I see: on fiddle it works but the divs on fiddle have no height just a top value, if you add height like any div would have it causes the issue.

Comment: oh i see it on jsfiddle

Comment: @MunkhdelgerTumenbayar on fiddle it works but the divs on fiddle have no height, if you add height like any div would have it causes the issue.

Comment: can you make js fiddle on your case ?

Comment: <a> in html: Link to an element with a specified id within the page (like href="#top")

Comment: @Jesse I am doing that

Answer (score 0):

Found a far better solution to what I had above and I made a codepen for it.

https://codepen.io/LukeD1uk/pen/MVeGQW

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var windscroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (windscroll >= 100) {
        $('section').each(function(i) {
            if ($(this).position().top <= windscroll - 0) {
                $('nav li.active').removeClass('active');
                $('nav li').eq(i).addClass('active');
            }
        });

    } else {

        $('nav li.active').removeClass('active');
        $('nav li:first').addClass('active');
    }

    }).scroll();
```